# Jquery based File Explorer/Manager

Tags: jquery

Is there a demo of jQuery based File Explorer or Manager, similar to Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a better one...

http://elrte.ru/en/elfinder/demo

**Update**

demo - https://studio-42.github.io/elFinder/

source - https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder

Comment: The link is dead, it redirect to some other page.

Answer (score 2):

Just did a quick google search and came accross: http://kfm.verens.com/

demo at: http://kfm.verens.com/demo/trunk/index.php?lang=en

Comment: How did I miss that search result. Gr8 this uses just jquery ui alone.